2 Menu right clickable items
So I have 2 RMK menu items. Both menuitems will start Class1.java. Is there a way to find out in the RCP Class1(extends org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage) like get_MenuItem_Selected(), to find out if "menuItem1" selected or "menuItem2" selected?
Regards,
Jemrug

Not sure I understand what you mean by "start Class1". If you are constructing a new class why can't you just pass a parameter to the constructor saying which menu item created it - or call different methods in the class.

@greg-449 sorry I manage to solve this. What I meant is , starting the class is done by an action, I created a new Action.
